# Question mark in field name of SQL INSERT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

This may be a futile question, but I will ask anyway.  I have now learned that it is bad practice to use a question mark at the end of a field name, as is the case with the `Paid?` field in the following statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tblAppeals` 
( 
`#`,
`Year`,
`Property#`,
`Paid?`,
`Outcome`,
`ResolvedBy`,
`AppealCategory`
) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

When I try to run the statement, I get an error because the question mark is not handled correctly.  I haven't been able to find any workarounds to avoid having to go back and change the field name.

Is there any way I can keep the field name the same, `Paid?`, and still use it in the INSERT statement?  Thanks.

Comment: Name `paid?` can not make any problem when you are using it as enclosed by tilda(`) check your values and field names and field count. You can share your error description. It will be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its an issue with your query layer and not MySQL itself. That is, whatever is doing the bind params handling is eagerly looking for all `?` in the SQL and not just whats in the `VALUES` part of the clause.

What database drive / query framework are you using?

Comment: Hi Cody.  I'm using MySql db and Codeigniter framework.  No idea how to resolve what you are suggesting.

Comment: Ok so it sounds like an issue with CodeIgniter. I think at this point you're better off not using `?` in your field name. Otherwise you're faced with having to dig deep into CodeIgniter to patch how it handles field names, etc.